# Is it possible to find a delegated event on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

When placing a handler to an element via `$.on()`, is there any way to find the delegated event when all you have is the target?

EX:

`$('body').on('click', '#myLink', function(){ doStuff() });`

...

`$('#myLink').eventsFromOn();`

I know this seems odd, because if the event has the delegate event data, its not really a delegated event anymore, but its worth it to ask...

Thanks!

Comment: i ***think*** you can get them with something like this `$("#myLink").data('events').click[0].handler`

Comment: In your example, are you looking for `body` or `#mylink`? Or something else entirely? The question is really unclear.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: no, when using normal `click` events yes, but when using `on()` the target element does not contain 'events' data

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't entirely sure, just tested

Comment: its too bad, but it makes sense I suppose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for handler data, looks like you can find it with undocumented information if you try hard enough. On the undocumented `events` data object, you have the keys `type`, `handler`, and — importantly — `selector`. So if you start with `#mylink`, you can look at the `events` data at each level in its ancestry looking for a match for your desired event where `$("#mylink").is(selector)` is true.

For example, with this HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="mylink">click me</div>
</body>
```

If I execute

```
$("body").on("click", "#mylink", function() {
    // Anything
});
```

Then do this:

```
var level = $("#mylink");
while (level[0]) {
  console.dir(level.data('events'));
    level = level.parent();
}
```

I get this:

```
undefined
  No Properties
Object
  click: Array[1]
    0: Object
        data: undefined
        guid: 1
        handler: function () {
        namespace: ""
        origType: "click"
        quick: Array[4]
        selector: "#mylink"
        type: "click"
        __proto__: Object
        delegateCount: 1
        length: 1
        __proto__: Array[0]
        __proto__: Object
undefined
  No Properties
```

As you can see, the `click` hander on `body` is there, with a `selector` matching the element `#mylink`.

Comment: hmm, so it would basically be a recursive function traveling up to the `document` at most...didn't wanna go there, but if it comes down to that...

Comment: @andbeyond: Not recursive, but definitely a loop. Probably a loop within a loop (outer loop being the levels of ancestry, inner loop being through the array of handlers).

Comment: ya either way, not entirely favorable, but it doesn't look there is a more efficient way, so this approach gets the cake, thanks!